# gsl: make file not linking, /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl

Tags: linux, matlab, gcc, makefile

I am getting following error on linux server

> `gcc -m64 -O3 /export/projects/EL/mlml21/gsl-1.16/.libs/libgsl.a   /export/projects/EL/mlml21/gsl-1.16/cblas/.libs/libgslcblas.a -I/export/projects/EL/mlml21/gsl-1.16 -std=c99 -o em em.c data.c prob_functions.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl
>   `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
>   make: *** [em] Error 1'

by running the following makefile

> `default: em em_mex`
>   clean:
>   `  rm -f *.o em
>
> `CBLAS_LIB=/export/projects/EL/mlml21/gsl-1.16/cblas/.libs`
>   GSL_LIB=/export/projects/EL/mlml21/gsl-1.16/.libs
>   `GSL_INCLUDE=/export/projects/EL/mlml21/gsl-1.16`
>   MATLAB=/usr/local/R2013a
>   `em_mex: em_mex.c em.c data.c data.h prob_functions.c prob_functions.h`
>   $(MATLAB)/bin/mex $(GSL_LIB)/libgsl.a $(CBLAS_LIB)/libgslcblas.a -I$(GSL_INCLUDE) -arch=linux em_mex.c em.c data.c prob_functions.c
>
> `em: em.c data.c data.h prob_functions.c prob_functions.h`
>    gcc -m64 -O3 $(GSL_LIB)/libgsl.a $(CBLAS_LIB)/libgslcblas.a -I$(GSL_INCLUDE) -std=c99 -o em em.c data.c prob_functions.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`

Answer (score 3):

Try installing libgs by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

You are compiling your program from source.  gcc searches the library named gsl when linking but cannot find gsl on your system.  That's the main reason why gcc command failed.  Your system does not have gsl installed. Therefore you must install gsl before your program can be compiled.  To install gsl, simply run the above command.  Hope this helps.